# How to scale TileMap in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

My question is **specific** about [Phaser game engine](http://phaser.io/)

I'm completely new to the Phaser so maybe I'm missing something simple here. I'm trying to write a simple **mobile** game and I'm having troubles finding tutorials/sources/examples about **mobile** aspects of game dev using Phaser.

In my game I have a few stages and a game is defined like:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(gameWidth, gameHeight, Phaser.AUTO, 'main');

game.state.add('Boot', myGame.Boot);
game.state.add('Preloader', myGame.Preloader);
game.state.add('Stage11', myGame.Stage11);
```

in the 'Boot' I'm setting up scale

```
var myGame = {};    
myGame.Boot = function (game) {

};
myGame.Boot.prototype = {
    init: function () {

        this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.USER_SCALE;
        this.scale.setUserScale(myGame.Metrics.scaleX, myGame.Metrics.scaleY);
        this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
        this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;

    },
    create: function () {


        this.state.start('Preloader');
    }
};
```

myGame.Metrics.scaleX and myGame.Metrics.scaleY determined based on some logic I found online. Basically we assume that game is 800 x 500px and depending on the current dimensions we are finding our scaleX and ScaleY

Preloader is big, here is a tile portion:

```
myGame.Preloader = function (game) {
    var fx;

};
myGame.Preloader.prototype = {
    preload: function () {
        this.load.tilemap('Stage1-1', 'assets/MY/Stage1-1.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
        this.load.image('Tiles', 'assets/MY/tiles.png');
        this.load.image('car', 'assets/sprites/car90.png');
    },

    start: function () {
        this.state.start('Stage11');
    }

};
```

And the last piece is Stage11:

```
myGame.Stage11 = function () {
};

var sprite;
var cursors;

myGame.Stage11.prototype = {

    create: function () {
        this.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        this.map = this.add.tilemap('Stage1-1');

        //the first parameter is the tileset name as specified in Tiled, the second is the key to the asset
        this.map.addTilesetImage('Tiles', 'Tiles');

        //create layer
        this.blockedLayer = this.map.createLayer('blockedLayer');

        //collision on blockedLayer
        this.map.setCollisionBetween(1, 2000, true, 'blockedLayer');

        this.blockedLayer.resizeWorld();

        sprite = this.add.sprite(50, 50, 'car');
        sprite.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);

        this.physics.enable(sprite);
        this.camera.follow(sprite);

        cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    },

    update: function () {

        sprite.body.velocity.x = 0;
        sprite.body.velocity.y = 0;
        sprite.body.angularVelocity = 0;

        if (cursors.left.isDown) {
            sprite.body.angularVelocity = -200;
        }
        else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
            sprite.body.angularVelocity = 200;
        }

        if (cursors.up.isDown) {
            sprite.body.velocity.copyFrom(this.physics.arcade.velocityFromAngle(sprite.angle, 300));
        }

    },
    render: function () {
        // Camera
        this.game.debug.cameraInfo(this.game.camera, 32, 32);
    }
};
```

My TileMap was created using "Tiled" and it is 20x200 tiles (each tile is 70x70px) so it is 1400px by 14000px here it is:
[image: My TileMap]

And that's how it looks like on Simulator:
[image: Simulator]

I'm a little bit desperate at this point. Here are a few questions:

1. How to make TileMap to fit the screen (let's assume screen size is
   going to vary)?
2. Do I need to resize the TileMap?
3. What's wrong here?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Richard no I didn't and I gave up on Phaser. It is good, it is fun, but some things just doesn't work out-of-the-box, so you have to jump thru so many hula hoops. Well... didn't work for me.